# How do you fix an access denied error debugging a dotnet app in a container?

Tags: docker, rendering-host

While debugging in Visual Studio I receive the following error:

[image: Access is denied]

This previously worked but something recently changed to break this. Perhaps related to a change made in Docker Desktop for Windows 4.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you start with a default console app with Docker support. It would seem that the access required in the container to run the remote debugger has changed.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj", "ConsoleApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleApp1"
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
USER ContainerUser
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

Update the `base` stage to the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
USER ContainerAdministrator
WORKDIR /app
```

Doing this allows Visual Studio to connect to the remote debugger and run elevated. Be sure to downgrade to **ContainerUser** on the final stage.

### Container Security

Microsoft shares some details about container security in the article [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-security).

> We strongly recommended that when deploying a Windows server container to any multi-tenant environment that your application runs via the **ContainerUser** account.

The images you build for distribution should be configured with **ContainerUser** to minimize risk to your environment.